# Conditional Logic to connect generic .Net method arguments

Tags: c#, .net, generics, conditional-statements

I have a C# method something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<T2> SomeMethod<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> arg1)
{

}
```

and I would like to be able to do some conditional logic so that if T1 is A then T2 is B and so on. This is not a problem if I just have those two constraints. However, what if I also wanted logic such as if T1 is C then T2 is D.

The check can be done in the method of course, but a compile time check would be preferable.
What I would like is to specify this in the generic where statement of the method.

Is there any way to do this in C# or any other .net language?

For more information T1 is basically a data object and T2 is a specifier that pertains to the T1 data object. All valid T1's are a certain base class while all valid T2's are a different base class. They are two different classes but are always used together.
The problem I am trying to avoid is having in the code data and a different specifier which doesn't go with the data passed in together.

Comment: Can you give examples of the conditions? The .NET type system allows only a couple of very special conditions to be placed on generic type arguments.

Comment: Why are you using generics for something that's clearly not generic?  Consider using a hammer instead of a backhoe the next time you want to pound in a nail.  (Protip: Generics aren't templates.  If you try to use them like some sort of bizarre string replacement mechanism, you're in for a world of C++-y hurt.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you want just isn't expressible in .NET constraints. It sounds like actually you *might* be better off with simple overloads... but we don't really know enough to say.

If a method is only suitable for a few type arguments - or a few combinations of type arguments - then it might not really be appropriate to be a generic method in the first place.

EDIT: Given this information, it may make more sense:

> For more information T1 is basically a data object and T2 is a specifier that pertains to the T1 data object. All valid T1's are a certain base class while all valid T2's are a different base class.

It's not really clear what you mean by a "specifier" here, but it sounds like you might want T2 to be expressed in terms of an interface which relates it to T1. For example, if these are *actually "entity" and "decorator-for-entity" types, you might have:

```
private static IEnumerable<T2> SomeMethod<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> arg1)
    where T2 : IDecorator<T1>
```

... where `IDecorator<T>` is a new interface. Again, there's still not really enough information to say, but this sort of thing *can* be a valid approach.

Comment: @romkyns: Not really: it's answering the question of "Is there any way to do this" with the answer of "no".

Comment: I guess the "we don't really know enough to say" bit made me say that.

Comment: I added more information, but I am fairly certain you are right in that it is not possible in the c# syntax.

Comment: @romkyns: We don't know enough to say what the best alternative approach is, but I *can* say that there's no way of expressing the constraints requested...

Comment: @nawfal Yes, and I think outright refusing to question someone just because they’re generally good is a bad idea. Besides, this answer has expanded quite a bit since that first comment was made.